# How to increment a variable within a python if statement

Tags: python, macos, if-statement, syntax

I am trying to increment a variable based on a condition in the if statement. Every time I attempt to do so, I get a Syntax error on the equal sign, and I'm not sure why. I am writing this in the Python IDLE

[You can click on this link to access the image of the code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RHYte.png)

Comment: 1) Curly brackets are not supported in Python, you only need indentation to define a block; 2) Post text, not images

Comment: Are you trying to create a `dict`?

Answer (score 1):

Python doesn't need { at start of condition phrase and } at the end of it. delete them and try again :)

Comment: Thank you! This worked! I was getting Python confused with Java :)

Answer (score 0):

You are writing python with incorrect syntax.

In python, we use indents to indicate the start of for and while loops instead of brackets ('{' and '}').

Your code should look like this (the indentation is crucial):

```
if var == 9:
    num = num + 1
    print(num)
```